# Is $\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

I have some trouble with the following problem:

> Problem. Whether the ideal $I=\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ or not?

**Solution**. For this I check whether the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is a field or not. So if we take $J=\langle 5\rangle$ then by 2nd isomorphism theorem we have: $$\mathbb{Z}[x]/I \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/J}{I/J}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{I/J}.$$

Now we have to calculate the ring $I/J=\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle/\langle 5\rangle.$ I am suspecting it to be isomorphic to $\langle x^2+1\rangle.$ To prove this I try to use 1st isomorphism theorem.

So I have to define a epimorphism from  $\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle$ to $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ whose kernel is $\langle 5\rangle.$  The natural intuition should be to define the map $\phi:\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle \to \langle x^2+1\rangle$ by $(x^2+1)f(x)+5g(x) \mapsto (x^2+1)f(x).$ Then it will be a homomorphism, moreover onto. Now clearly, $5\mathbb{Z}[x] \subset \ker \phi$. Again if an element is of the form $(x^2+1)f(x)$ then it doesn't map to $0$. So $\ker \phi=\langle 5\rangle.$

Therefore by First Isomorphism theorem $\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle/\langle 5\rangle \cong \langle x^2+1\rangle.$
 Then $$\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1, 5\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle.$$

Now as the latter ring is not an field (since $x^2+1$ is not an irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$) so the given ideal is not an maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Is this proof is correct? Please tell if I made any mistake. Thank you.

Comment: In general. maximal ideals in $\Bbb Z[x]$ is $(p,f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_p$

Comment: How to prove this..?

Comment: see https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/voloch/Homework/zx.pdf

Comment: $x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3)$ in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: Is my proof  right?

Comment: Yes$ \dots \dots$

Comment: thank you......

Comment: It might be easier to see if you factor by $x^2+1$ first, since the only thing that remains are linear polynomials, and factoring $(5)/(x^2+1)$ is easy: $5$ survives in the quotient. So you're looking now at linear polynomials in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ which are not invertible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3) \in \mathbb Z_5[x]$, so it is not irreducible, and your proof is correct.